# Google PlusOneButton leaks a context

Tags: android, memory-leaks, google-play-services, google-plus-one, leakcanary

I've started tracking memory leaks on my Android app and, thanks to the great [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) library, I found that some of my activities that include a `GooglePlusButton` are leaking a context.

Unfortunately I didn't find a workaround to avoid it. As described on this [old bug report](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=943), the initialize method hides the fact that its needs a context. Furthermore, it needs an Activity context; the Android studio decompiler shows it (the bug reporter tell it as well):

```
public void initialize(String var1, int var2) {
   zzab.zza(this.getContext() instanceof Activity, "To use this method, the PlusOneButton must be placed in an Activity. Use initialize(String, OnPlusOneClickListener).");
```

Is there any workaround better than completely get rid of the +1 button?

Note: I'm using Google Play Services 9.6.0 but this problem also occurred on previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

As it is said in the error message if you are using G+1 button not in an activity (for example in the app bar menu) you need to initialise it by calling method *initialize(String, OnPlusOneClickListener)*.

> Updates the +1 button with a URL. Most apps call this method each time the button is in focus (for example, in the Activity onResume method). To use this method, the PlusOneButton must be placed in an Activity. **Use initialize(String, OnPlusOneClickListener) otherwise**.

More info here:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusOneButton

Comment: Thanks for your comment but my issue is using G+1 button in an activity; leading to a context leak.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer points me in a new direction. I finally manage it by creating the G+1 button dynamically and giving the constructor the Application context:

```
mPlusOneButton =  new PlusOneButton(getApplicationContext());
parent.addView(mPlusOneButton);
...
mPlusOneButton.initialize(..., new PlusOneButton.OnPlusOneClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlusOneClick(Intent intent) {...}
      });
```